# How to add an image to TreeItem in Material UI (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

How to add an image or picture to TreeItem in Material UI?

In documentation of Tree view is using an svg icons (Gmail clone
) [Tree view](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/)

I can use my set of svg icons as well:

```
function MyIcon(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <svg ...>
        <path d="..."/>
        ...
      </svg>
     </SvgIcon>
  );
}
<TreeView...>
  <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="My Node" icon={MyIcon()}/>        
</TreeView>
```

or implement StyledTreeItem as shown in the material-ui example:

```
function StyledTreeItem(props) {

  return (
    <StyledTreeItemRoot
    
      label={
           
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', p: 0.5, pr: 0 }}>  
        <Box component={props.myIcon} color="inherit" sx={{ mr: 1 }} />            
            {props.labelText}
        </Box>
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
```

But how to use an image as JPG, BMP or PNG in TreeItem?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I did the following:

```
import myImage from './img/myimage.png';
    
<TreeItem 
 nodeId="1" 
 label={ 
  <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>  
    <img src={myImage} />
    <Typography
      variant="body2" 
      sx={{ fontWeight: 'inherit', marginLeft: '5px'}}>
       Node Text
    </Typography>                  
 </Box>
 }
>
```